# Android Animation: Difference Between android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/xyz" and android:interpolator="@android:anim/xyz"?

Tags: android, animation, android-animation, interpolation

I was applying **interpolator** to my `<objectAnimator>` present in **res/animator** directory and found that there are two ways I could apply interpolator by using:

1. `android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/bounce"`
2. `android:interpolator="@android:anim/bounce_interpolator"`

Can someone explain difference between them?